# how to display results using sql where name starts from initial A - D

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display results from a db table of names, i only want to display names with initial A - D, like starting with a,b,c and d. I wonder if we can use multiple values with LIKE clause, as in LIKE a%,b%,c%,d%. I wonder if it will work and if there is a more appropriate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple `LIKE` clauses separated by `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR name LIKE 'B%' OR name LIKE 'C%' OR name LIKE 'D%'
```

Or you could use a regular expression (`REGEXP`):

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-Da-d]'
```

**Edit**

Here's another method using `UCASE`, `SUBSTR`, and `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE UCASE(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most compact way is:

```
select t.*
from t
where left(name, 1) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Or, even shorter:

```
select t.*
from t
where left(name, 1) between 'A' and 'D';
```

Note that although these are caps, the comparisons are probably case-insensitive (the default on MySQL), so 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' will match these.

Or, you could make it even shorter with the somewhat esoteric:

```
select t.*
from t
where name >= 'A' and name < 'E';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is a wildcard character is used to represent any character, and  for that reason is probably not what you want.

A better approach would be to use mysql `REGEXP` so you query becomes:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM people WHERE first_name REGEXP '^[A-z]';`
```

You can find more here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that I can quickly figure out is:
`SELECT field_a FROM`table`WHERE field_a like 'a%' OR field_a like 'b%' OR field_a like 'c%' OR field_a like 'd%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.* from t where name between 'A' and  'E';
```

should work